# Why POST request will be called multiple times based on the array during submit form via ajax to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I push the id into the array when checkbox is `checked`.

```
var items=[];
$("#selection").click(function(e) {
       $(":checkbox").each(function() {
            if(this.checked === false) {
                this.checked = true;
                items.push(this.id);
            }
        });
});
```

When I submit, the item saved to database but at the "network monitor', it displays a lot of `POST` request which is unusual.

```
$('#grid').submit(function(e){

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
            });
            e.preventDefault();

            var formdata = {
                item:items
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/addItem",
                data: formdata ,
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    swal(
                        'Great!',
                        'Item added!',
                        'success'
                    ) ;
                }
            });

        });
```

During submit the first value is always pass null, but all data will be saved as expected just the POST request will be called based on the number of item in items array. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: from this codesnippet I cant see a reason. Can you provide more code around your submit event handler? Did you maybe add the submit event multiple times to your form?

Comment: When i submit for the first time, everything just work fine. The POST request happen e.g i have a pagination with 3 pages then it will be called 3 times to store the data. For the second time, it will pass null value and get internal server error. E.g. i add 1 item at first, after success then i add one item again, then will get internal server error but the item will be saved also. And continue add third item, 2 internal server error will be occurred and data will be saved as well. ... so on.

Comment: Sorry, if cant get what i mean, i can explain in more details.

Comment: Or you just provide more code as I asked. From what you showed no one can tell what is wrong.

Comment: which part of code do you need to have a look?